# Neo4j Desktop Creating Database Hanging

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

Recently, past 10 minutes, installed Neo4j desktop with the intention of testing it's abilities. I had worked previously with the browser implementation a few years back and had no problems.

With Neo4j Desktop the application is hanging on "Creating a new database...", has been around 10 minutes already. Is this normal behaviour and the database creation is a long running tasks or is this abnormal and issues have arisen?

Comment: It's not normal, except if you have a very low internet connection (desktop downloads the correspondig neo4j version). Do you have a proxy or some security rules on your network?

Comment: @logisima Creating a local database, working within my organisation so there are tight restrictions. No prompts for admin rights however.

Answer (score 0):

Been told that this is a known problem with Windows 7 and to to be fixed "soon".
A workaround is to download the community edition and separately install a suitable Java version.